# Horizontal scrollbar on full-width three column row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm having the following three columns layout:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <title>youpi</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJ
kqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">hey</div>
      <div class="col-md-5">hey</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">hoo</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Sadly the padding of the last col make an horizontal scrollbar appear:
[image: unwanted scrollbar shown]

Is there someting I'm doing wrong? IIRC it did not happened in bootstrap 4.

(Tested in Firefox 92 only.)

Answer (score 0):

Hello Julien there is a margin-right on the row class and it is messing up with the layout.
You could reset this margin to fix the layout

Comment: Is it a bootstrap bug? Or is it expected to behave like [css mug](https://www.xonot.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/CSS-Is-Awesome-Mug-Left-11oz.jpg) on the first example I test?

Comment: I was able to fix it using `.row {--bs-gutter-x: 0;}` what's `--bs-gutter-x`? Does not look like a css attribute :D also it modified the padding, not the margin.

Answer (score 0):

Oh it was the documented in the [bootstrap 4 to 5 migration documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/migration/#grid-updates) I did'nt fully read:

> Breaking Renamed .no-gutters to .g-0 to match new gutter utilities.

`sed -i s/no-gutters/g-0/` fixed it!